# Gerar Danfe a partir do XML da NFe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, nfe

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação `ASP.NET MVC` com `C#` e preciso transformar `XML` de NF-e para Danfe em `PDF`, alguém sabe algum componente para isso?

Comment: Componente pra que? Pra gerar o PDF? Ou você quer um componente em que você joga o XML e ele monta a Danfe?

Comment: Preciso enviar o xml da nfe e gerar o pdf da danfe.

Comment: Vamos do começo. Tente ser o mais claro possível. Você já consegue gerar e enviar o XML, certo?

Comment: Eu já tenho o XML da NFE, oque eu quero é passar esse xml para a aplicação e ela me retornar o danfe em pdf já nos padrões, queria algum componente open source, porque criar do zero, vai dar muito trabalho.

Comment: Dá trabalho mesmo. O meu eu escrevi. O bom de usar um pronto é... que tá pronto :) problema de usar um pronto é que cada vez que mudar alguma coisa, você tem que torcer pro pessoal atualizar ele, pq se nao atualizarem logo, aguente cliente na orelha :)

Comment: Complementando o comentário do @Bacco, você pode usar algum framework no github, por exemplo, e criar um fork para você e assim você alterar direto nele. Faço isso quando não existe a funcionalidade que quero no framework e não quero esperar a atualização do projeto original. Eu altero o meu e depois proponho a alteração no projeto original, já que você também precisa contribuir com ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numa simples busca no Google eu encontrei o [Danzor](http://www.yanjustino.net/open-source-danzor/), parece fazer exatamente o que você precisa.

Para instalá-lo, abre o **Package Manager Console** e digite

> PM> Install-Package Danzor

No seu controller crie uma instância de DanzorPrintViewr passando o path onde está o XML da NFe

```
public ActionResult Danfe()  
{
    var model = new DanzorPrintViewer("<<caminho do arquivo>>");
    return View("~/Views/Danfe/Danfe.cshtml", model);
}
```

<sup>Exemplo tirado do site do componente</sup>

Comment: Tentei esse componente, porem ele não instala aqui, da o seguinte erro: `Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Danzor'.`

Comment: Deve ser algum problema com sua configuração do Nuget. Veja, o componente ainda está disponível https://www.nuget.org/packages/Danzor/

Comment: @henriquedpereira Entre no chat se precisar de ajuda com o nuget

Comment: Di boa não consegui, mas baixe o fonte deles, vou criar o meu pegando como base o deles, vlw.